# Check if embeded Tomcat was started

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I am embedding Tomcat 7 into my Java application. In the constructor I set the variable:

```
this.tomcat = new Tomcat();
this.started = false;
```

I then have another method called at a later point to start it:

```
this.tomcat.start();
this.started = true;
```

I use the `this.started` variable to keep track of whether I ever started the server. Means that the state of the server is kept multiple times (internally by Tomcat and again in the variable). Ideally, I would like to just use the Tomcat API to get the status of the server, but I have not been able to find a method to do it.

The best alternative that I have found is trying to open a connection to the server. It seems like a slow (in CPU time scale) and resource inefficient solution.

Comment: What you want to do? Verify if your app is running? Verify if Tomcat is running? Or something else?

Comment: @DavidFeitosa I omitted a lot of code. We have configuration that can be changed, but only when the Tomcat is not yet started or was stopped. If the user tries to reconfigure a running server, we want to throw an IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.tomcat.getServer().getState();

or

this.tomcat.getServer().getStateName();

Those are standard Lifecycle methods and can be called on the Server or any Engine, Host, Context, Connector, Realm etc.